# Getting way worse results after switching from bidirectional_rnn to bidirectional_dynamic_rnn

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

basically tried to substitute bidirectional_rnn with bidirectional_dynamic_rnn (reshaped inputs), and got way worse results on a classification task.
Am I doing something wrong? Reshaping?

bidirectional_rnn version (code excerpt):

```
encoder_embedded_inputs = [embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(
                    W, encoder_input) for encoder_input in encoder_inputs]

encoder_outputs, encoder_state_fw, encoder_state_bw  = rnn.bidirectional_rnn(
                    encoder_cell_fw,
                    encoder_cell_bw,
                    encoder_embedded_inputs,
                    sequence_length=sequence_length,
                    dtype=dtype)

encoder_state = array_ops.concat(1, [array_ops.concat(
                1, encoder_state_fw), array_ops.concat(1, encoder_state_bw)])
top_states = [array_ops.reshape(e, [-1, 1, cell.output_size * 2])
                              for e in encoder_outputs]
attention_states = array_ops.concat(1, top_states)
```

Classification Accuracy: 95%

bidirectional_dynamic_rnn version (code excerpt):

```
encoder_embedded_inputs = [embedding_ops.embedding_lookup(
                    W, encoder_input) for encoder_input in encoder_inputs]
emb_size = int(encoder_embedded_inputs[0].get_shape()[1])
enc_size = len(encoder_embedded_inputs)
birnn_inputs = tf.reshape(encoder_embedded_inputs, [-1,enc_size,emb_size])

encoder_outputs, encoder_states  = rnn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
                    encoder_cell_fw,
                    encoder_cell_bw,
                    birnn_inputs,
                    sequence_length=sequence_length,
                    dtype=dtype)
encoder_state_fw, encoder_state_bw = encoder_states
encoder_state = array_ops.concat(1, [array_ops.concat(
                1, encoder_state_fw), array_ops.concat(1, encoder_state_bw)])

attention_states = tf.concat(2, encoder_outputs)
```

Classification Accuracy: 70%

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found that tf.reshape is not suitable for this task, I should have used tf.stack and tf.transpose instead.
So basically it was using messed up inputs, and was no longer able to learn.

Wrong:

```
birnn_inputs = tf.reshape(encoder_embedded_inputs, [-1,enc_size,emb_size])
```

Right:

```
birnn_inputs = tf.stack(encoder_embedded_inputs)
birnn_inputs = tf.transpose(birnn_inputs, [1,0,2])
```

So now it works well.